# Nesting Classes within an ID in the .css?

Tags: css

Okay heres my .css

```
.centerhex {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4sZDtfK.png);
    height:224px;
    width:210px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.transtart{
    opacity:0
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    0%{opacity:0;}
    40%{opacity:1;}
    50%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0%{opacity:0;}
    40%{opacity:1;}
    50%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
.done{
    animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
}
.fadein{    
    animation:fadein 0.65s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 0.65s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
    0%{opacity:0.05;}
    10%{opacity:0.1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0%{opacity:0.05;}
    10%{opacity:0.1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
.pulse{ 
    animation:fadein 4s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-delay:1s
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

What I was curious about is if it is possible to create an id specifically for nesting predefined classes, such as:

```
#hexa.centerhex.transtart.fadein.done
```

So far experiments in doing this have failed.. so Im not entirely sure what Im doing wrong.

The idea I have for this is that Im going to be creating some script that replaces an ID with another ID. For instance I would make:

```
#hexa.centerhex.transtart.fadein.done
```

Turn into:

```
#hexb.centerhex.transtart.pulse.done
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate how(and where) you've failed? I'm not sure I understand the question. Although, if you are giving an ID to one of your elements, you shouldn't need to mention any class, just `#hexa{/*CSS style*/}` would do

Comment: When you say "#hexa.centerhex.transtart.fadein.done" that means an element with id="hexa" and class="centerhex transtart fadein done". So yes it won't work like that.

Comment: @drip Why won't it work? See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Le2aj/

Comment: @tewathia yep sry, didn't see there was a class for pulse and fadein too, I thought he was using directly the names for the keyframes.

Comment: In my experience, CSS is usually pretty picky about semicolons.  Even if it's only one:  `.transtart{ opacity:0 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're asking but it seems like you're hoping for an unrealistic result based on the ordering of your classes that you typed out.  The rendering won't go in a certain order based on selectors you choose unfortunately.

However, this can be done with Javascript fairly easily using a `setTimeout()` if timing was an issue.

And if you don't care about the order of operations on these classes being added to each `id`, then you should be able to do this as much as you want (and with reasonably high success as the `#id` is only trumped by `!important` and client-side/browser settings).

Don't forget your `semicolons` :)